# Update mySQL record without page refresh and animate link to disappear

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am struggling with a solution to my problem. I have created the code and works fine in PHP but I now want to evolve this into a better working solution for the end user.

I have a set of links to confirm or deny an action. Once the users clicks "Confirm"/"Deny" I would like this to save value to db using AJAX and then make the `li` animate out with jQuery.

At the moment i have used php, which redirects to URL. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Heres my code:

**links**

```
           <?php    

            $friend_unconfirmed_from_them = mysql_query('
            SELECT * from wallfriends 
            where mem_id_to ='.$USER->id.' AND confirm = 0
            '); //unconfirmed friends to logged in user ($USER->id)

        while ($friendrequest = mysql_fetch_array($friend_unconfirmed_from_them, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 


        $senders_name = mysql_query('
            SELECT firstname, lastname from mdl_user 
            where id = '.$friendrequest['sender'].'
            '); //get unconfirmed friends name

        while ($sender = mysql_fetch_array($senders_name, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
            ?>

        <li><?php echo $sender['firstname'].'&nbsp;'.$sender['lastname']; 
            }?>            
        <a href="confirmfriend.php?userid=<?php echo $friendrequest['sender']; ?>">Confirm Link</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="removefriend.php?userid=<?php echo $friendrequest['sender']; ?>">Deny Link</a></li> 
//echo each friend in li with confirm deny links
            <?php } ?>

        </ul>
```

**confirmfriend.php**

```
$userid = optional_param('userid', 0, PARAM_INT);


$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "on10n") or die ("Unable to connect!");   
mysql_select_db("fe") or die ("Unable to select database!");    
$query = "UPDATE wallfriends SET confirm = 1 WHERE mem_id_to = '$USER->id' AND mem_id_from = '$userid'";    

$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 
if (!$result){
    echo "There were errors :<br>". mysql_error();
} 
else{ 
redirect($siteUrl.'/profile.php?userid='.$userid.'');
die;  
}
```

**denyfriend.php**

```
$userid = optional_param('userid', 0, PARAM_INT);


$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "on10n") or die ("Unable to connect!");   
mysql_select_db("fe") or die ("Unable to select database!");    

$query = "DELETE FROM wallfriends 
WHERE (mem_id_from = '$USER->id' OR mem_id_from = '$userid') 
AND (mem_id_to = '$USER->id' OR mem_id_to = '$userid') 
";    

$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 

if (!$result){
    echo "There were errors :<br>". mysql_error();
} 
else{ 
redirect($siteUrl.'/profile.php?userid='.$userid.'');
die;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre not showing any javascript and the anchor will throw the page onto confirmfriend.php/removefriend.php.

Also you have multiple nested anchor tags (remember to close with `</a>`)

To achieve desired result, i'd do so:

```
<li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="confirm friendaction"
      data-userid="<?php echo $friendrequest['sender'];>">Confirm</a>
</li><li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove friendaction"
      data-userid="<?php echo $friendrequest['sender'];>">Remove</a>
</li>
```

Followed by a script which hooks onclick to anchors, sending an AJAX request.

```
<script>
   $('.friendaction').click(function() {
       var id = this.getAttribute('data-userid'),
           url = this.className.match("confirm") 
              ? "confirmfriend.php" 
              : "removefriend.php", 
           liReference = $(this).parent();
       $.ajax(url + "?userid=" + id, {
           complete: function() {
              $(liReference).fadeOut();
           }
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the response, this is working great for the confirm deny function, but it does not seem to fade the desired li out. Any ideas?

Comment: ADDED: <li id="newfriend<?php echo $friendrequest['sender']; ?>"> then ...........            complete: function() {
              $('#newfriend'+id).parent().fadeOut();
           } and now works great!!!

Answer (score 3):

You should read upon the jQuery [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) functions. You might be interessted in the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and/or $.post functions. All of these functions provide you with a success/failure callback, where you can [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) (or [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)) the desired elements.

Basically, you just grab the data you want from your page and pass it to the jQuery functions. Since your PHP functions are already doing what they should, this should be a minor task once you got around the jQuery functionallity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery-Ajax for this.

For example

**User Interface HTML code**

```
<li><?php echo $sender['firstname'].'&nbsp;'.$sender['lastname']; 
            }?>            
        <a id="confirm" data-userid="<?php echo $friendrequest['sender']; ?>">Confirm Link</a>
        &nbsp;<a id="deny" data-userid="<?php echo $friendrequest['sender']; ?>">Deny Link</a></li>
```

**jQuery-Ajax**

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#confirm").click(function(e){

        $.ajax("confirm.php?userid=" + $(this).attr("data-userid"), {
                   complete: function() {
                      $(this).parent().fadeOut();
                   }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
        });
         $("#deny").click(function(e){
        $.ajax("deny.php?userid=" + $(this).attr("data-userid"), {
                   complete: function() {
                      $(this).parent().fadeOut();
                   }
        });
    e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

I did not tested the code. Hope it will give an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response, although I could not get this working.

Comment: what is the problem you are getting? :)